# convert array into key value pairs

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have following array,

```
Array
(
    [Char100_1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Char100_1] => Mr S Kumar
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Char100_1] => Mr S Kumar2
                )
        )

    [Char100_13] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Char100_13] => 159.9
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Char100_13] => 119.9
                )
        )

    [Char100_14] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Char100_14] => 191.88
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Char100_14] => 143.88
                )
        )
)
```

which is created dynamically from a database query result and some loops.

Now I wanted to convert this array into something like below,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [Char100_1] => Mr S Kumar
        [Char100_13] => 159.9
        [Char100_14] => 191.88
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [Char100_1] => Mr S Kumar2
        [Char100_13] => 119.9
        [Char100_14] => 143.88
    )
)
```

I have tried looping through them but its not working.

```
<?php
    /* database process to create array */
    $contentArray = array();
    foreach($newData['DataField'] as $ndata) :
        $responsedata = getAppContent($appid, $ndata);
        while($haveresult = mysql_fetch_assoc($responsedata))
        {
             $contentArray[$ndata][] = $haveresult;
        }
    endforeach;

    /* for getting resulting array start */
    $newdataArray = array();

    foreach($contentArray as $field => $value):
        $newdataArray[$field] = array();
        foreach( $value as $val ) :
             $newdataArray[$field] = $val;
        endforeach;

    endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: Way better to "fix" this at the data query level than to transform the array afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change the query (as suggested in the comments), then the following should work:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($array as $a) {
  foreach ($a as $k => $b) {
    if (empty($output[$k])) {
      $output[$k] = array();
    }
    $output[$k] += $b;
  }
}
```

Comment: yes its worked...thanks a lot....now can you please tell me how can i remove those associative array to normal o indexed keys

Comment: Change `$output[$k] += $b` to `$output[$k][] = current($b);`

Answer (score 1):

I observe that you are transposing the arrays. i.e all the zero subscript values together and all the one subscript values together.

Therefore your outer subscript should be the '0' and '1'. These are available in the inner loop. So, the inner loop index becomes the outer array index. And the inner loop value, which is an array, you need to take the 'current' value of.

```
/* for getting resulting array start (PHP 5.3.18) */
$newdataArray = array();

foreach($contentArray as $field => $value):
    foreach( $value as $idx => $val ): // $idx takes value 0 or 1. $val is an array
      $newdataArray[$idx][$field] = current($val);
    endforeach;

endforeach;
print_r($newdataArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as all of your arrays have the same amount of values containing them a for loop will do:

```
$NewDataArray = array();

for ($a = 0; $a < $Numberofvaluesineacharray; $a++){
$NewDataArray[$a] = $NewDataArray[$array1[$a], $array2[$a],.....arrayn[$a];
}
```